# screen resolution issue for master page

Tags: .net, html

I have a master page in .net. I have a list of images as module icons top. I have used div under div for it, when I change the resolution from high to low, it goes down in two lines, please suggest me

Comment: Please show your CSS code ...

Comment: show some code,how can we know what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

your Question is not so detailed ..so i am trying to answering you very basics.
if you have used `px` for height and width in your `CSS` , remove them ..and try to give the height and width in percentage.

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
```

Comment: I have used percentage only bu when I zoom my screen, it comes in two lines.

Comment: .container{
 width:100%;
}
/*css for main navigation */
.top-nevigetion
{
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-color: #6B919C;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
    /*height: 100px;*/
}
.top-nevigetion-left{
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    background-color: #8DC5D2;
    background-image: url(../../../App_Themes/Theme/WorkingWindow/images/new_top-nevigetion_image.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom;